# How to add .jar dependency files in JNI C++ environment

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

So, I've been trying to find a way to run my java code along with its dependency .jar files in Visual C++ program.

**I used the following code to run java program in C++ with out any problem.**

**Java Code**

```
public class Sample2
{
 public static int intMethod(int n)
 {
   return n*n;
 }
  public static boolean booleanMethod(boolean bool) 
  {
   return !bool;
  }
}
```

**C++ Code**

// 1.cpp : main project file.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "jni.h"
 #include <windows.h>
 using namespace System;


int CallJava()
 {
  JavaVM *jvm;   /* denotes a Java VM */

  JNIEnv *env;  /* pointer to native method interface */

  jint square;

  jboolean not;

  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */

  JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[1];

  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\JavaCode";  

  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

  HINSTANCE hinstLib;  

   hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\Program   Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_45\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll"));

 if(hinstLib==0)
 {
  printf("Error");
  }

  if(hinstLib!= NULL)
 {
  typedef jint (JNICALL *PtrCreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **, void **, void *);

   PtrCreateJavaVM ptrCreateJavaVM =     (PtrCreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(hinstLib,"JNI_CreateJavaVM");

  int res = ptrCreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

   jclass cls = env->FindClass("Sample2");

   jmethodID mid;   

  if(cls !=0)
  {   
   mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls,"intMethod","(I)I");
    if(mid !=0)
   {  
     square = env->CallStaticIntMethod(cls, mid, 5);       
     printf("Result of intMethod: %d\n", square);
   }

  mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "booleanMethod", "(Z)Z");
  if(mid !=0)
  { 
    not = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(cls, mid, 1);
    printf("Result of booleanMethod: %d\n", not);
    }
 }
  jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
 }
else
{
  printf("Library is NULL");
}
   Console::Read();
   return 0;
 }

 int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
 {
 CallJava();
 Console::Read();
 return 0;
 }
```

Now, my question is that since my following java program uses a few jar files from a directory.

**Java Code**

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import es.unex.sextante.core.Sextante;
 import es.unex.sextante.gui.core.SextanteGUI;

 public class Demo5 
 {

 public static class Starter implements Runnable 
 {
     public void run() 
     {
        Sextante.initialize();
        SextanteGUI.getGUIFactory().showModelerDialog();

     }
  }

    public static class GUI implements Runnable 
   {
     public void run() 
     {
        try 
        {
           SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Starter());
        }
        catch (Exception exc) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
     }
 }

   public static void run() 
   {
    Thread gui = new Thread(new GUI());
    gui.start();
   }   

 }
```

I am able to compile and run the java code via command prompt by using the following approach:

Compile: 
        javac -cp c:\Lib\sextante.jar;c:\Lib\sextante_gui.jar; Demo5.java

Run: 
        java  -cp c:\Lib\sextante.jar;c:\Lib\sextante_gui.jar; Demo5

However, I don't know how to add the jar files in JNI approach.

```
I tried the following ways:
```

a. Method 1: The following approach doesn't work:

```
    JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[3];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\JavaCode";  
    options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Lib\\sextante.jar"; 
    options[2].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Lib\\sextante_gui.jar";
```

b. Method 2: I am trying to find the jars in the method call...

Nothing works fine yet. Would you please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[3];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\JavaCode";  
options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Lib\\sextante.jar"; 
options[2].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Lib\\sextante_gui.jar";
```

would be converted to the command

> java.exe -Djava.class.path=C:\JavaCode -Djava.class.path=C:\Lib\sextante.jar -Djava.class.path=C:\Lib\sextante_gui.jar

What you probably want to do is:

```
JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\JavaCode;C:\\Lib\\sextante.jar;C:\\Lib\\sextante_gui.jar";
```

which gets converted to

> java.exe -Djava.class.path=C:\JavaCode;C:\Lib\sextante.jar;C:\Lib\sextante_gui.jar

Comment: Thanks Mike for the response. Unfortunately after I change it the way you mentioned, I'm still getting the same error that class not found error.   I tried the way you mentioned then I tried in the following way too.    JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[1];  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\APP3;C:\\APP3\\*.jar";  I'm wondering that is there any jar files arguments should I need to pass in CallStaticVoidMethod()

Comment: You cannot wildcard JVM options like that.  Typically using "*" (also known as "globbing") is something handled by your shell environment, not the JVM.

Comment: You need to enumerate each jar file you use individually.  Referring to a directory only works for referencing unbundled class files.